# cmake (Windows 10): How to check full compiler input

Tags: cmake, mingw

I need to check which options and flags are passed to compiler during build. Printing out environment variable doesn't show anything. It's just empty.

CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1 FATAL_ERROR)
project(GtestExample LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

message(STATUS "compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")

#adding subdirecotories, linking libs etc
# ...

add_compile_options("-O0")
add_compile_options("-Wall")
message(STATUS "C++ compiler flags: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

Windows terminal output:

```
C:\Users\NDanashevskii\Documents\cplusplus\cplusplus_test\cmake_out>cmake ..
-- compiler C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
-- C++ compiler flags:
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/NDanashevskii/Documents/cplusplus/cplusplus_test/cmake_out
```

Could you please support in solving this issue?

Comment: The command `add_compile_options` doesn't modify `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable. Instead, it modifies `COMPILE_OPTIONS` directory property. It is clearly stated in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/add_compile_options.html). And `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is not an *environment* variable. It is CMake variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Correct, thank you for your answer. But COMPILE_OPTIONS variable is empty as well even after `add_compile_option()` usage. Is there any way to check all compiler flags in summary?

Comment: A *variable* and a *property* are different things in CMake. "Is there any way to check all compiler flags in summary?" - When build the project with `make` (after `cmake`), you may pass additional option `VERBOSE=1`. So every executed command line will be printed, and you may check that compiling your executable or library uses required compiler flags.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Executing `cmake --build ./ -- VERBOSE=1` shows me inputs for `cmake.exe` and `mingw32-make.exe` but not for `g++.exe`. Could you please tell how can I check g++ inputs?

Comment: Hm, this should work: `mingw32-make VERBOSE=1`. Note that only those command lines are printed which are actually executed. That is if your executable is already built and doesn't need to be rebuilt, nothing will be printed. You may run `mingw32-make clean` for remove already build files.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks a lot! `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` or `cmake .. -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON` show full make output during clean build as well.

Answer (score 0):

To check compiler inputs full `make` utility execution should be switched on during `cmake --build`. There are few ways:

1. `cmake ..` then `mingw32-make VERBOSE=1'
2. `cmake .. -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON` then `cmake --build . -- VERBOSE=1`
3. Add `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` to CMakeLists.txt and `cmake --build . -- VERBOSE=1`

And execute build after clean to check full output.